# Use of undefined constant LF with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, typo3

Hello everyone,

I'm developing a TYPO3 extension and I've ran into this very strange situation. I have a unit test for a class but when I ran it I get the `Use of undefined constant LF - assumed 'LF' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)` error.

The <kbd>LF</kbd> character is the Line Feed or new line character used in *nix systems. Windows is using <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> combination.

I am on Windows 10, having the most recent version of PHP 7.4 and xdebug on it. I also have WSL2 Ubuntu with PHP 7.4 (no xdebug). I use PHPStorm as my IDE. PhpUnit version 9.5.

I get this error message when I run the test in IDE (Windows context), CLI (Ubuntu context) and docker container (also 7.4, alpine Linux).

I was running it in debug mode in the IDE as well and I got to a point that exception is thrown on this statement in my UT:

```php
$pageRendererMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class)
      ->setMethods(['addJsInlineCode'])
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
```

As soon as the `getMock()` is called exception is thrown. So I dug deeper.
I got to the PhpUnit's `MockClass::generate()` method. It has the following snippet of code in it:

```php
eval($this->classCode);

call_user_func(
    [
        $this->mockName,
        '__phpunit_initConfigurableMethods',
    ],
    ...$this->configurableMethods
);
```

The `__phpunit_initConfigurableMethods()` method comes from the `\PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Api` trait.

By debugging further I got to a this line in the `MockObject\Api::__phpunit_initConfigurableMethods()` trait's method:

```php
if (isset(static::$__phpunit_configurableMethods)) {
```

I have a breakpoint on this line. When I step over it I get the exception.

The funny thing is that there's no literal `LF` anywhere in code!

Have you ever got into this problem? How have your solved it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I all files in repo have Linux style line endings (`LF`) but I tried to convert them to Windows format (`CRLF`) but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use of undefined constant LF

The PHP constants `LF`, `CR` and `CRLF` are defined by TYPO3 bootstrap at a very early point: `SystemEnvironmentBuilder->run()` calls `defineBaseConstants()`. They are "convenient" constants to type `LF` instead of `chr(10)`.

If your unit test scope does not have them, it's a strong sign your extension test setup does not properly bootstrap TYPO3.

A typical setup to take care of that is having a UnitTests.xml file for phpunit that references a UnitTestsBootstrap.php. See the example boilerplate files in [typo3/testing-framework](https://github.com/TYPO3/testing-framework/tree/main/Resources/Core/Build) for good practice and copy those over to your setup, or if you have them already, make sure your phpunit call uses the .xml file (-c option). Extensions like [b13/container](https://github.com/b13/container) are also a good read to study more sophisticated test setups for extensions that are actively maintained and support multiple core versions.